# fail to build and install pyopencv on Mac OS Mountain lion

Tags: python, opencv

I have downloaded pyopencv and installed opencv and boost.When I try to build and install pyopencv,I got errors like the follow.It really bothered me so much!!:

I got all prerequisites ready for pyopencv on my platform.And I succeeded in using cmake command.Then I cd to the build folder I just create trying to run make and make install command, I got the errors messages below.Seems like the conflict among the pyopencv,opencv and the Boost.Python. Here is the platform I use and the version of the pyopencv ,opencv and Boost.Python.

**PyOpenCV 2.1.0.wr.1.2.0 with Opencv 2.4.3

My OS is Mac OSX  10.8 Mountain lion**

**here is the entire error message:**

In file included from /Users/shuxuan/Engineering/ProjectsofPyOpenCV/pyopencv/package/extras/core/opencv_headers.hpp:9:
/Users/shuxuan/Engineering/ProjectsofPyOpenCV/pyopencv/package/extras/sdopencv/sdcxmat.hpp:180:13: error: 
      constructor for 'cv::Mat' must explicitly initialize the member 'size'
      which does not have a default constructor
inline Mat::Mat(const Mat& m, const Rect& roi)
            ^
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:1976:11: note: member is declared here
    MSize size;
          ^
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:1948:23: note: 'cv::Mat::MSize'
      declared here
    struct CV_EXPORTS MSize
                      ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.
    make[2]:  [CMakeFiles/pyopencv_extras.dir/package/extras/core/ndarray.o] Error 1
    make[1]: [CMakeFiles/pyopencv_extras.dir/all] Error 2
    make:  [all] Error 2

All the errors are like the above...I don't know why.

Comment: First and foremost, put huge blocks of text into a code tag or something. No one likes scrolling for minutes at a time.

Comment: Also, why does it look like you're copying and pasting from a code.google.com bug report/issue report? And maybe, take a look at this and see if it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4577696/has-anyone-ever-had-opencv-work-with-python-2-7-on-macos-10-6

Comment: Just out of curiosity, have you tried doing this on Ubuntu? I have friends that use OpenCV, but they do it on Linux.

Comment: Yeah!I just copy the issue from the project on the code.google.com.I submitted the issue there but it seems there is no one still there so I come here for help.And,I didn't try that on linux.It says it is available on MacOS.And I have got all the prerequeisites ready.It's just the the incident happened when I try to build and install pyopencv using make and make install command.

Comment: Ok, I don't know enough to help you here. I'm sorry.

Comment: That's okayy!thanks for asking!but do you know other wrappers for opencv?I just discovered the cvtypes,also using python for wrapping.But it's said it's been outdated.So if there are any other ones that I can use to simplified the coding,that will be much better!